# DSolve with particular boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following equation:

```
sol2 = FullSimplify[
ExpToTrig[
DSolve[{s''[y] == (2 (s0 (k1 + k2) - k2 s[y]))/(
B t) , (s[l - L] == s0)}, s[y], y]]] /. (
Sqrt[2] Sqrt[k1] )/(Sqrt[B] Sqrt[t]) -> λ
```

I would like to insert another boundary condition in order to impose that B*s'[y] is constinuous in y=l-L.
How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you think that it is discontinuous there?

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher this is the bc in eq. (11) in https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822318305580

Comment: This does not answer my question. Btw.: If it is really a _boundary_ condition, what do you mean by "continuous"? Or do you mean to find an equation mediating between two domains with a common interface? What I try to say: There is a lot of context missing. And please don't expect us to dive into an article behind a paywall if your question is about a simple ODE. Unless you invest a bit more of effort, you propably won't get a good answer here.

Answer (score 2):

If I modify your solution to

```
Y = FullSimplify[ExpToTrig[DSolveValue[{s''[y] == (2 (s0 (k1 + k2) - k2s[y]))/(B t), (s[l - L] == s0)}, s,y]]]
```

Y[y] is the general solution of your ode with one boundary condition, depending on `C[1]` as a free parameter.

The condition for smooth `y'[l-L]` is limited second derivative

```
Y''[l - L] // FullSimplify
(*(2 k1 s0)/(B t)*)
```

`Y''[l - L]` doesn't depend on the free parameter. That means you can, assuming `b t!=0`, choose arbitrary b.c. to achieve smoothness!